# Convert From Google Publisher Tags to iFrames on DFP Server

Tags: javascript, iframe, asynchronous, double-click

I am trying to convert the DFP tags on my website from DPT to iFrames for asynchronous rendering of the website. The problem is that I have already implemented rich media on my tags such as expandable banners; however, when using iFrames, the rich media banners do not work well.

The tutorial I followed is: https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/117857. It did not work out what I need. Maybe I have something wrong with the links.

I read a lot about the issue and found out we need to implement some code to release the banner from the iFrame restrictions (dynamic iFrames to expand with the banners). I downloaded the javascript file (DARTIframe.html) and hosted it on my website's server under the directory (files/dclk/DARTIframe.html). Below is the code used for the iFrame tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ord = window.ord || Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e16);
  document.write('<iframe src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N7229/adi/mywebsite/homepage;mtfIFPath=/files/dclk/DARTIframe;sz=728x90;ord=' + ord + '?" width="728" height="90" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
</script>
<noscript>
  <a href="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N7229/jump/mywebsite/homepage;sz=728x90;ord=[timestamp]?">
  <img src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N7229/ad/mywebsite/homepage;sz=728x90;ord=[timestamp]?" width="728" height="90" /></a>
</noscript>
```

Inside the tags I used mtfIFPath to link to the DARTIframe.html file. I do not know if I am doing it the right way. What I know is that what I have done did not work.
I need a step by step process to convert my tags.